# InstallData categories not add the categories

Tags: magento2, category, magento-2.1.3, installdata

I make and installData to define new categories (I have a lot of categories and sub-categories and I don't know why but they are nor added, in the database I see they are added but it's strange see the picture).

In my installData I create a new Category object from Magento\Catalog\Model\Category

In my install function I put this :

```
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
  {
    $setup->startSetup();

    // get datas to insert the categories
    $categories_data = $this->getCategoriesData();

    // Insert all main categories
    foreach ($categories_data as $category_data)
    {
      $this->insertCategory($category_data);
    }


    $setup->endSetup();
  }
```

So I get my datas by the getCategoriesData function which return me an array like :

```
[
  'data' => ['name' => 'A category', 'parent_id' => 3],
  'childs' => [
    [
      'data' => ['name' => 'A sub category 1'],
      'childs' => [],
    ],
    [
      'data' => ['name' => 'A sub category 2'],
      'childs' => [
        [
          'data' => ['name' => 'A sub category of sub category 2'],
          'childs' => [],
        ],
      ],
    ],
  ]
],
[
  'data' => ['name' => 'A category not in menu', 'parent_id' => 3, 'include_in_menu' => false],
  'childs' => [],
]
```

And in my insertCategory function I put :

```
private function insertCategory($category_data)
  {
    $category = $this->_category->setData($category_data['data'])->save();
    if (!empty($category_data['childs']))
    {
      foreach ($category_data['childs'] as $category_child)
      {
        $category_child['data']['parent_id'] = $category->getId();
        $this->insertCategory($category_child);
      }
    }
  }
```

So if the category have an array child which is not empty, I add a new data 'parent_id' to the child data key. But I don't know why, this not work. Look at the screen of my database, the parent_id of the Childs is the id of the child, it's not possible, I dont understand why... I define a parent_id = 3 to put theses in a root category test I created but they are not showed in the back office. (I have run bin/magento setup:upgrade and bin/magento cache:flush).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Be aware of `addData` and `setData` methods.

The magento\Framework\DataObject said:

```
/**
 * Add data to the object.
 *
 * Retains previous data in the object.
 *
 * @param array $arr
 * @return $this
 */
public function addData(array $arr)
{
    foreach ($arr as $index => $value) {
        $this->setData($index, $value);
    }
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Overwrite data in the object.
 *
 * The $key parameter can be string or array.
 * If $key is string, the attribute value will be overwritten by $value
 *
 * If $key is an array, it will overwrite all the data in the object.
 *
 * @param string|array  $key
 * @param mixed         $value
 * @return $this
 */
public function setData($key, $value = null)
{
    if ($key === (array)$key) {
        $this->_data = $key;
    } else {
        $this->_data[$key] = $value;
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Illustration:

```
$data = [
    'a' => 'b',
    'c' => 'd',
];

addData(['a' => 'z']);
// data['a'] replaced by 'z', result: ['a' => 'z', 'b' => 'd']

setData(['a' => 'z']);
// data is cleared and filled by given parameter, result: ['a' => 'z']
```

Try to replace your `setData` with `addData`:

```
private function insertCategory($category_data)
{
    // $category = $this->_category->setData($category_data['data'])->save();
    // change above code with this one, and give a try
    $category = $this->_category->addData($category_data['data'])->save();
    if (!empty($category_data['childs'])) {
        foreach ($category_data['childs'] as $category_child) {
            $category_child['data']['parent_id'] = $category->getId();
            $this->insertCategory($category_child);
        }
    }
}
```

And see if it works.